# Why there is high-frequency noise from audio interface when I switch on my computer?

Tags: audio, noise, interface

I have an audio interface: a Focusrite clarett+ 4pre. When it is NOT connected via USB to the computer, but connected to the same power filter (computer is grounded, focusrite has no ground contact), I start hearing high frequency random noise (not white noise, but something more crunchy, like random peaks at some frequencies). Thanks for your reply!

Phases are correct.

Comment: Can you clarify, if the computer is turned off, there's no noise from the Clarett? Can you explain what you mean by "computer is grounded, focusrite has no ground contact"?